# SharePoint Online - Concatenate multiple field values into Title field

Tags: sharepoint-online, concatenate

Looking for a way to concatenate multiple field values [Created By] and [Category] into the "Title" field as [Created By - Category] either using column formatting or calculation values. I'm not very familiar with these in the online environment at all and have not found anything remotely close in my searches. Thank in advance!

Comment: You can show the concatenated values in title field using JSON column formatting. But note that this will not store/set the value in Title field. It will just show the concatenated value in list view.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Here is my SharePoint list

[image]

2.**Title** >> **Column settings** >> **Format this column**

[image]

3.On the Format panel, click "**Advanced mode**" link

[image]

4.Please use the below JSON formatting:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=[$Author.title] + ' - ' + [$Category]"
}
```

[image]

**Note:**

- `"$Author"` is the internal display name of `[Created By]`

[image]

- The JSON column formatting does not change the data in the columns;
  it only changes how it’s displayed to users who browse the list.
  Therefore, the actual value of [Title] is not "Created By -
  Category".

[image]